# Como inserir um video em HTML?

Tags: html

Não consigo inserir um video na minha pagina já fui inclusive ao w3school ver e não resultou.
Eu não quero inserir um video do youtube, eu quero inserir um que está na minha pasta.

Answer (score 3):

Antes do HTML5, um vídeo só pode ser reproduzido em um navegador com um plug-in (como flash).

O elemento HTML5  especifica uma maneira padrão de incorporar um vídeo em uma página da Web.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="caminho para o video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
```